# More than one .xml file in res/menu folder

Tags: android

When I have more than one xml file in my res/menu folder it only recognises one of them.  I would like to have one Action bar for a certain activity and a different one for another.  I take it this isn't some kind of illegal action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare several files under res/menu. They only need to have different names.

For example

```
res/menu/
  --menu_one.xml
  --menu_two.xml
  --menu_three.xml
```

is completely valid.

You'll need to reference them during menu creation via `R.menu.menu_one`, `R.menu.menu_two` or `R.menu.menu_three`.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not illegal. Usually you have several menu xml files and you use what you want in your Activities.

for you... ¿Whats the meaning of 'recognise'?